# Error Kendo UI Chart graph e.slice is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, graph, kendo-ui

Hi i am trying to graph using Kendo Chart but it gives me a error:

```
 var datosConFormato={}
            for(var x=0;x<datos.datos.length;x++){
                var dato={};
                dato.DIA=datos.datos[x][0];
                dato.TOTAL=datos.datos[x][1];
                datosConFormato[x]=dato;
            }

            $("#chartEvolucion").kendoChart({
                chartArea: {
                    height: 200
                },
                dataSource: {
                    data: datosConFormato
                },
                legend: {
                     position: "bottom"
                 },
                series: [{
                    type: "column",
                    field: "TOTAL",
                    name: "Total de consultas por días"
                }],
                seriesColors: ["#03a9f4"],
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    template: "#= dataItem.DIA # - ${ value } Consulta(s)"
                }
            });
```

And the error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function
at init.success (kendo.all.min.js:11)
at Object.success (kendo.all.min.js:11)
at init.read (kendo.all.min.js:11)
at kendo.all.min.js:11
at init._queueRequest (kendo.all.min.js:11)
at init.read (kendo.all.min.js:11)
at init.query (kendo.all.min.js:11)
at init._query (kendo.all.min.js:11)
at init.fetch (kendo.all.min.js:11)
at init._initDataSource (kendo.all.min.js:58)
```

It does not throw values into the plane
DIA is a String and TOTAL a number, what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to add ".d" to the datasource binding. I had similar issue when i migrated from .net 2.0 to .net 4.5 adding ".d" resolve my issue i don't know why, but you can give a try.

```
dataSource: {
                data: datosConFormato.d
            }
```